# How to add multiple values with while statement?

Tags: java, sum

I'm trying to ask user to type how many numbers will be inputted and enter the values then add all the values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sum {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int counter = 1;
        int values = 0;
        int times; 

        System.out.println("How many numbers will you input?: ");
        times = sc.nextInt();

        while(counter == times){

            System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
            values = values + sc.nextInt(); 
            counter ++;

        }

        System.out.println("Your sum is " + values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for the while loop is incorrect.

```
while(counter == times)
```

will only be true if counter and times have the same value. So if you would want to input two numbers, your while loop wouldn't even get executed. What you want is for the while loop to run *until* counter == times. So, your logic should be

```
while(counter != times)
```

Furthermore, you should start your counter at zero, instead of one. This is because it now means that you already inputted one number, which you didn't.

Alternatively, you could use the following snippet

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    values += sc.nextInt()
}
```

This simple loop will go through all the integers inputted in the command line one by one, until there is no next integer (you type for example a letter).

In that case, you don't need to ask the user how many numbers he/she will input, as you will check it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. btw, is there any other way ask user to enter multiple numbers without setting "How many numbers will you input?"
basically, add all the numbers whatever user input without having "time" variable.

Comment: Yes, you could do the following:

`while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
 values += sc.nextInt();
}`

Comment: @jyr you can update your answer with the code you provided in your comment, it would be better for future readers

Comment: Good suggestion. Just did that!